Why when i put a variable block into a statement block the value changes from 50,000 to 0?
Im making a cookie clicker game and i have cookie per click upgrades, there is a cost that starts at 50,000 cookies then everytime you buy it, it multipies by 100. But when i put the cost variable into any statement the value changes to 0 for somereason, why?
If i buy an upgrade the cost turns into 0, because of the problem explained above. But when i take the cost variable out of the statement, it goes back to 50,000, why?




can you make it a test project and send link(it works as supposed when I use just ur code), make minimal project and send it if there is issue in it, or send whole project if issue occurs only in full project, not minimal project.

I don't see how this is possible based on the code shown here. Are you sure there isn't other code also making modifications to these variables? There's no universe where ceil(100 * 50000) == 0 is possible, unless there's some numerical overflow, which this is too low to cause.

50,000 is not a numeric value in Scratch, 50000 is! Due to the thousand separator, your value will be treated as zero when used inside a numeric expression.

i will try what you said @RuudHelderman

@RuudHelderman, it tried it and it worked, tysm, you are the best

This is because you cannot put separation characters in variables if you want your variable to be a pure number.
If your variable is 50000 (let's call this var1), and you add a comma to it so it becomes 50,000 (call this var2) Scratch will treat the var2 as not a numerical value!
And so Scratch will handle this by just evaluating 50,000 * 100 to 0.

